# Am I properly using induction to prove this about the Ackermann function?

Tags: induction, ackermann-function

Using induction, I want to prove that $ A_0^{x-1}(1) = x $ for $ x > 0 $ where 
$$ A_m(n) = A(m, n) $$
and
$$ A_m^k(n) = \underbrace{A_m(A_m(...A_m(n)...))}_\text{k A's} $$

After proving the base case, I assume that $ A_0^{n-1}(1) = n $ is true. My inductive hypothesis is 
$$ A_0^{(n+1)-1}(1) = n + 1 $$

Is this correct?

Comment: On the second line, do you mean to say that$$A_m^k(n)=A_m(A_m(\dots A_m(n)\dots))$$?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks for pointing that out! I did mean to say that. I'll edit it now.

Comment: If you wanted to an induction proof, I'd probably write it as $$A_0^{n-1}(1)=n\implies A_0^{(n+1)-1}(1)=A_0(A_0^{n-1}(1))=A_0(n)=n+1$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I see! I knew I hadn't set up the inductive hypothesis correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*from the comments...*

"After proving the base case, I assume that $A^{n−1}_0(1)=n$ is true."

Thus, you want to use $A_0^{n-1}(1)=n$ as your induction hypothesis so that you may get

$$A_0^{n-1}(1)=n\implies A_0^{(n+1)-1}(1)=A_0(A_0^{n-1}(1))=A_0(n)=n+1$$

as desired.